# Which option to choose when signing digitally in Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

When I tried to sign digitally on adobe acrobat, I have 2 choices: PKCS#12 and Windows Certificate Store. Which one should I choose? What's the difference?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to store your certificate as a flat file or stored in the certificate store for the user on the system? Only you can decide what is more appropriate.

Comment: @Ramhound On what system? I'm on a personal computer that's trying to sign an employment contract in a PDF. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The system that will store the certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You arrive at this screen when creating a new personal digital signature.
The question here is where you wish the signature to be stored.

You have two options :

> - **New PKCS#12 digital ID file**   Stores the digital ID information in a file, which has the extension `.pfx` in Windows and `.p12` in Mac
>   OS. You can use the files interchangeably between operating systems.
>   If you move a file from one operating system to another, Acrobat still
>   recognizes it.
> - **Windows Certificate Store**   Stores the digital ID to a location on your computer where other Windows applications can also retrieve
>   it.

It's not as easy to port to other computers from the
Windows Certificate Store, as you need to export the
certificate from the Store, but it's more easily accessed
by applications in your computer.

Reference :
[Manage Digital IDs in Acrobat](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/digital-ids.html).